# Want to find dimensions of 1993 Honda Civic steering knuckle for repair reasons

Tags: honda, civic, parts

I am repairing a 1993 Honda Civic (EG8) front suspension.  I Want to find dimensions of the front steering knuckle and other suspension parts for repair reasons.  I am just checking if the original has been bent as it has been in a crash.

Where could I get this sort of information?

I don't want to reverse engineer it but I do need to check the relevant dimensions to see if it has been bent.

Hoping someone can guide me:)

Comment: you might want to check with a body shop. they have books for this iirc.